# grep: printing different patterns on different lines

Tags: grep, line

Here is a sample list:

```
apple
pear
orange
orange
apple
orange
pear
orange
pear
orange
apple
```

What I am trying to achieve is to print a full *orange* line **only** if the line after (below) has *apple* in it (and this line will also be printed). Using the list above, grep would return the lines marked by a hyphen:

```
apple
pear
orange
-orange
-apple
orange
pear
orange
pear
-orange
-apple
```

Here is my best attempt so far, I start the command with *strings*:

```
strings fruits.txt | egrep 'orange' -A 1 'apple'
```

But it returns "grep: apple: No such file or directory".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting challenge. I think that `sed` would be a better tool for that job.

```
sed '/orange/ N; /orange.*\n.*apple/ !{D; N;};' fruits.txt
```

Comment: Hi Jinsky, thank you for your reply. I am afraid it does not really work yet. It returns 'pear' lines as well. Is it because I use it this way: sed '/orange/ N; /orange.*\n.*apple/ !{D; N;};' fruits.txt | strings   ?

Comment: I 'stringed' the original file into a separate file, and the output is different: it only returns one 'orange' line.

Comment: I wonder why is that. It is working on my machine (classic). ;) How is your new file different from fruits.txt?

Comment: The file is a huge data file, so impossible to post, but the lines start as described above (orange, apple, pear etc.). Wait, my bad, perhaps there are no orange/apple configuration in the file. It prints plenty of orange pear but not orange apple.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Any idea on how to also print the line after or the line below the pattern (orange apple)? An equivalent of egrep '-A' or '-B'? Essentially: once the pattern is identified on the two lines, then print line before and line after.

Comment: or to jump lines? I am trying to add '.*\n.*' For example, sed '/orange/ N; /orange.*\n.*\n.*apple/ !{D; N;};' fruits.txt if apple is two lines below, but it does yield any results :(